# How to properly decode a SCALE-encoded string using polkadot-js?

Tags: polkadot-js, scale-codec

Using `@polkadot-js/api`, one can encode a string `aabbcc` into `0x18616162626363`

```
> u8aToHex(api.createType('String', "aabbcc").toU8a())
"0x18616162626363"
```

I know that SCALE encoding adds the length info at the beginning of the encoded result, so in total the output is 7 bytes instead of 6.

However, when I try decode the output back to a string, the leading byte is treated as part of the string instead of being stripped out.

```
> api.createType('String', "0x18616162626363").toString()
"\x18aabbcc"
```

The expected result should be `aabbcc` without the initial `\x18` byte.

So, how to get rid of the leading byte when decoding a SCALE-encoded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to follow the same steps you took to generate the hex to get back.

In your example generating the hex you do:

1. String: `"aabbcc"`
2. `toU8a`: `Uint8Array(7) [ 24, 97, 97, 98, 98, 99, 99 ]`
3. `toHex`: `0x18616162626363`

On the way back, just do the same:

1. Hex string: `"0x18616162626363"`
2. `toU8a`: `hexToU8a("0x18616162626363")`
3. `createType`

So:

```
api.createType("String", hexToU8a("0x18616162626363")).toString()
> "aabbcc"
```